# Cómo traducir "baseline" en el ámbito de la tipografía

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

La imagen anexada explica el significado de varias palabras técnicas en tipografía e impresión digital. Me gustaría saber ¿cuál es la palabra española utilizada en el ámbito de la tipografía para la "baseline"? (*la linea roja que marca la base del texto en la imagen*)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que se denomina "**línea base**" o "**línea de base**".

De acuerdo  a este [glosario de términos de tipografía](https://tiposformales.com/2010/08/30/glosario-de-terminos-tipograficos/):

> **Línea base**: Línea imaginaria donde se encuentran apoyadas todas las letras mayúsculas y las minúsculas sin descendentes. En las minúsculas con descendentes, estos traspasan la línea base.

Nótese que las *descendentes* son de acuerdo al mismo glosario:

> **Descendente**: Trazo inferior de las letras minúsculas que se prolonga por debajo de la **línea de base**. Ejemplos de letras con descendentes: g j p q y

por lo que cuadra la definición de línea base (se apoyan todas la letras y solo la traspasan las prolongaciones de las letras minúsculas como la `j` en tu ejemplo).